# Developing OpenGLES2 apps for Ubuntu Software Center

Tags: software-center, application-development, opengl

I have a game for iOS and Android that I now want to port to Ubuntu.
I plan to distribute it with Ubuntu Software Center.
Preferrably for free with an in-app-purchase.

My codebase is currently based on OpenGL ES2 and written in C++.
I could rewrite to OpenGL, but having progammable shaders is a must.
Fixed pipeline OpenGL will not suffice.

Is there a feature in place that lets you specify OpenGL requirements in the Ubuntu Software Center? I want to make sure that only Ubuntu users with compatible hardware will be able to download my game.

Any APIs I could use for getting a suitable OpenGL context, or am I expected to just use glx for this? Or is the use of GTK mandatory?

Comment: Waiting for your game in software-center(I hope it is your popular crane game) :)

Comment: @Tachyons You can play Little Crane beta using http://stolk.org/tmp/littlecrane-1.0-5_i386.deb

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I got the following findings:

You can request an OpenGL-ES2 context from a regular OpenGL driver, as long as the OpenGL vendor supports this.

I've confirmed that this works with:

- Intel integrated graphics driver
- nVidia proprietary driver
- Radeon open source driver

And it does not work with:

- AMD/ATI proprietary fglrx driver

The extension to check for is GLX_EXT_create_context_es2_profile.
If you use the GLFW library, you can request it by doing:

```
    glfwWindowHint( GLFW_CLIENT_API, GLFW_OPENGL_ES_API );
    glfwWindowHint( GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR, 2 );
```

Answer (score 0):

*Disclaimer: I am not an opengl developer, So I don't know much about opengl*

**Is there a way to enforce minimum system requirements prior to purchase?**

You should specify minimum system requirements, for example video display, in your application description. However, there is no way to examine or enforce system requirements prior to purchase. If you want to check for system capabilities during installation you can run a custom program during the application installation.

[source](http://developer.ubuntu.com/publish/commercial-software-faqs/):